# Convert a string to JTextArea

Tags: java

I have a string "abc", I want to be able to display the string in a JTextArea called absencesText. But everytime I try

```
"absencesText.setText(abc)"     
"List absencesText =absencesText.asList(abc);"
"absencesText.append(abc);",
```

I get

incompatible types: java.util.List cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Im guessing this means String--->TextArea isn't correct. Anyway to display a string to a text area? Full code is below.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Action){
       if(Action.getSource()== tagTextField){

      System.out.println("Clicked");
      String searchObject = tagTextField.getText();
      try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(searchObject + ".0.txt"))) {

        List<String> abc = stream.filter(str->str.startsWith("433"))
        .map(s->s.split("433")[1]).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(abc); 
        // absencesText.append(abc);
        // List absencesText = absencesText.asList(abc);


    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

       }//TagTextField
```

If it matters, I do have a ScrollPane too.

Comment: "java.util.List cannot be converted to java.lang.String" means that you are giving a List but the method needs a String -> instead of collecting to a list (`...collect(Collectors.toList())`), use `...collect(Collectors.joining())` which joins to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the content of a `JTextArea` with a List of Strings (which is the type of `abc`). You can append your data to the JTextArea like this :

```
//Uncomment to clear the text of the JTextArea
//absencesText.setText("");
for (String string : abc)
  absencesText.append(string + "\n");
```

You can also build your string with a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and then call :

```
absencesText.setText(myStringBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you! The for (String string : abc)
  absencesText.append(string + "\n"); worked beautifully.